# Is there a way to stop receiving DMARC reports

Tags: dmarc

Is there a way to stop receiving DMARC email reports? I added the record to the DNS however, even after I removed that record I am still receiving email reports. I visited a DMARC checker website, just to see if my domain still has a DMARC record and it still does.

I find it really strange that even after I removed it from my DNS records, the reports are still coming through. Any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could only remove `rua` and it should stop sending you reports. How long you have removed the record in DNS?

Comment: It's been like over a month.

Comment: Could you identify the source of those reports? Contacting the sending source might solve the issue.

Comment: How many different places continue to send reports? you can always change the rua to "example@example.com"

Comment: If you remove the rua argument does the DMAR still work. I want to use DMARC but I don't want the emails. Seems quite a sane request.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest two options:

1. Remove your mails from the tags "rua" and "ruf"
2. I understand that to receive reports you have to authorize the reception in your DNS. If you did that you can undo it to stop receiving the reports.